# Connecting to Hana From Zend PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, hana

I want to connect to HANA Server hosted on cloudshare from PHP. Following code I am trying but still no luck. Please suggest the correct syntax, also I need to specify the `Server:Port` to set up `ODBC "User DSN"`. Where can I find the `Server:port`?

```
<?php
    $ServerNode='External Address';
    $DRIVER='HDBODBC';
    odbc_connect($DRIVER,$ServerNode,$user,$password, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC    
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP HANA Server `server` name is provided on your cloudshare VM list in VM details of your SAP HANA SPS5 server VM under `External Address` property. SAP HANA server `port` number is 30015. You can also have a look at [Connecting to your hana database from php using odbc](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2013/06/17/connecting-to-your-hana-database-from-php-using-odbc).